# I want to remove an entry in my $PATH

Tags: macos, terminal, android, path

I'm running OS 10.8. When I

```
echo $PATH
```

my terminal outputs

```
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/austinzuffi/Development/Android/adt-bundle-max-x86_64/sdk/tools
```

and i want to remove or at least edit

```
/Users/austinzuffi/Development/Android/adt-bundle-max-x86_64/sdk/tools
```

I can't find out where that string is entered. My /etc/paths shows

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

I'm assuming there's a file such as .bashrc that adds the entry upon login. I just can't find out which file is doing it. If you know which files might append my path environment variable, please let me know so I can check!

Also, if eclipse is modifying the system variable, let me know. I'm assuming eclipse doesn't have that power however I'm new to it.

Thanks guys
-Austin

Comment: Look in `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/bashrc`. If any of those files contain a line starting with either `source` or `.` (which is short for source) then look in the sourced files too. Quicker might be to use `grep`. Open a terminal and, from your home directory run `grep -r "/Users/austinzuffi/Development/Android/adt-bundle-max-x86_64/sdk/tools" .`.

Comment: @CraftyThumber This should be an answer, and not just a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/bashrc` for a line of the following form:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/austinzuffi/Development/Android/adt-bundle-max-x86_64/sdk/tools
```

Also look to see if any of those files contain a line starting with either `source` or `.` (which is short for `source`). If they do then look in the sourced files too.

A quicker way might be to use `grep`. Open a terminal and, from your home directory run

```
grep -r "/Users/austinzuffi/Development/Android/adt-bundle-max-x86_64/sdk/tools" .
```

Comment: `grep` a quicker way?! If you really don't know where it could be, this approach will take a **lot** of time. Do you know how long it takes grep to search through a 500GB hard drive? Long. In terms of certainty `grep` is the best choice, but not speed.

Comment: And HDs are bigger these days ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this Superuser article](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) for information about OS X path stuff. Of particular interest are the files in `/etc/paths.d/` and `~/.bash_profile` and the like.